# Should I render every page through a view function?

Tags: python, django

I have a simple static page that displays some information about the website. should i render this page via a render_to_response() even though it is static or should i simply display it as a normal html file?

the only thing I am concerned about is adding excess load on the server.

Comment: Serve static content as static. Not through django

Comment: May be the static content is not completely static. i.e it needs to use some django templates for header and footer and the inside content is static. eg. aboutUs page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worrying about server load, you should set up a  proxy like [squid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_%28software%29) or [varnish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varnish_%28software%29). The proxy can cache the static content so your server will only get a more one request every time the cache expires

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [Hyde](http://ringce.com/hyde), which uses Django and specializes in static content.

Comment: That version of Hyde hasn't seen an update in over a year. The new branch (which uses Jinja instead of Django) is [also on Github](https://github.com/hyde/hyde).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you're really talking about "static content" in the way Django developers usually do (Javascript, CSS, images, *etc.*).

You say you need Django templates, but imply the content on those pages doesn't need to be changed. This sounds like the perfect opportunity for the built-in Django `TemplateView` (example `urls.py` [from the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/class-based-views/#simple-usage)):

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^about/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="about.html")),
)
```

As gnibbler says, if you're very worried about performance then some kind of cache — Django actually [has caching built-in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/cache/), 
 and you can enable it for specific views with the [`@cache_page` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/cache/#setting-up-the-cache).